# Не работает disable-resize-watcher при малом экране без v-model

Tags: vuetify

Для управления отображения/Скрытия `v-navigation-drawer`, я не использую двунаправленную связь(`v-model`), так как мне необходимо переопреелять свойство. Состояние `v-navigation-drawer` храню в **Vuex**.

Разметка:

```
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-navigation-drawer
      app
      :value="v_navigation_drawer"
    />

    <v-app-bar
      :value="v_app_bar"
      app
    >
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon
        @click="toggleVNavigationDrawer"
      />
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-main>
      <router-view />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Проблема:
Прималых размерах экрана, если кликунь на оверлей, то `v-navigation-drawer` скроется, а значениее свойства `v_navigation_drawer` не изменится. Как сделать так чтобы значение свойства `v_navigation_drawer` тоже менялось?

Версия **Vuetify 2.2.11**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо сделать двунаправленную связь. Для этого на событие `input` необходимо повесить метод, где в первом аргументе будет текущее значение `v-navigation-drawer`. Затем его можно переопределить(обновить).

Разметка:

```
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-navigation-drawer
      app
      :value="v_navigation_drawer"
      @input="updateVNavigationDrawer"
    />

    <v-app-bar
      :value="v_app_bar"
      app
    >
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon
        @click="toggleVNavigationDrawer"
      />
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-main>
      <router-view />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Метод в **Vue**-компоненте:

```js
updateVNavigationDrawer(value) {
  this.$store.commit('UPDATE_V_NAVIGATION_DRIVER', value);
}
```

Метод в **Vuex**:

```js
UPDATE_V_NAVIGATION_DRIVER(state, payload){
  state.v_navigation_drawer = payload;
},
```